# MVC route with numbers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to route an old URL that is domain.com/1024 to my home page in mvc.

I keep getting resource not found errors.

Here is my routeConfig

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "1024",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Direct", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

My Controller

```
    public ActionResult Direct()
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: mydomain.com/Home/Direct works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your route definition before the default, for example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "1024",
  url: "{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Direct" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This will route (host):(port)/ to Index and (host):(port)/1024 to Direct where you can RedirectToAction("Index").

For example a HomeController to demonstrate the point (This ONLY redirects 1024 to index):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Direct(int? id)
        {
            if (id.HasValue && id.Value == 1024)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

    }
```

This would redirect any id to index:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Direct(int? id)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks dude, it works great I added a custom error tag to my web config to redirect all 404's but this works great. Thank You!